# Possible to insert a line into a file without having to read the entire file in C#

Tags: c#, memory-management, file-io

So this is just a thought... Say I wanted to insert a line into a file at the first linebreak, but I didn't want to read the entire file into memory. Is there a way to just read the file into memory line by line and then, when the first linebreak is reached, insert a line and close the file reader?

Thank you!

***Sorry for the earlier typo in my title/description***

Comment: Append or insert?  Append means the end of the file.

Comment: I meant insert, changing now... thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can read one byte at a time and intercept the line break character. Then at that position do a stream.WriteLine(). You'll hve to open file for read+write

Edit: I thought of using the FileStream object, but I'm not sure. Any for now try the suggestion mentioned here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/e5077949-5d23-4d26-a530-6d503745a197

Edit again: check [How to both read and write a file in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605685/how-to-both-read-write-file-in-c-sharp)

Comment: That won't work, you can't mix `WriteLine()` with `ReadByte()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText("test.txt"))
{
     w.Write("\r\nTest");
     w.Flush();
     w.Close();
}
```

**Update:**

For inserting the line in existing text file (I assume you're working with text files since you mentioned line break): there isn't a way to do it with file I/O API - you must read the text *after* the first line break, overwrite the file and add original trailing text.