# Write and read from same file

Tags: c#, filestream

I have been looking at writing a string into a file and then read it line by line, but I always get the error   IOException: Sharing violation on path C:...\level1.txt. I looked on the internet and they said I should use the same stream to write and read but it didn't work,so I tried to make a different stream for each one and it didn't work either.

```
FileStream F = new FileStream("level1.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(F);
        sw.Write(Gui.codeText.Replace("\n", "\r\n"));
        F.Close();
 FileStream F2 = new FileStream("level1.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        StreamReader file = new StreamReader(F2);
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        { ....}
```

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605685/how-to-both-read-and-write-a-file-in-c-sharp

Comment: that's what I was looking at, I tried the same thing but with FileStream F = new FileStream("level1.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);  StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(F); StreamReader file = new StreamReader(F); and I still got the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to use the `Using statement` while `read and write`.

Since the `StreamWriter` and `StreamReader` classes inherits `Stream`, which is  implements the `IDisposable` interface, the example can use using statements to ensure that the underlying file is properly closed following the write or read operations.

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(F))
{
      //Write Logic goes here...
}

using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(F2))
{
     //Read Logc goes here...
}
```

[*The Using Statement:*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664736(v=vs.71).aspx)

> An using statement is translated into three parts: acquisition, usage,
>   and disposal. Usage of the resource is implicitly enclosed in a try
>   statement that includes a finally clause. This finally clause disposes
>   of the resource. If a null resource is acquired, then no call to
>   Dispose is made, and no exception is thrown.