# C# Getting Runtime error : The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, .net, filestream

Here is my code: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiZqZ.png)

```
using System.IO;

namespace Randoms
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[10240]; // buffer size
            string path = @"C:\Users\RAHUL\Desktop\file.txt";
            using (FileStream source = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                long fileLength = source.Length;
                using (FileStream dest = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
                {
                    long totalBytes = 0;
                    int currentBlockSize = 0;

                    while ((currentBlockSize = source.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        totalBytes += currentBlockSize;
                        double percentage = (double)totalBytes * 100.0 / fileLength;
                        dest.Write(buffer, 0, currentBlockSize);                                                
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please check the image which shows the error which I am getting.I have tried to change the FileAccess multiple times but not getting any luck.

Comment: You create two stream from the same file so it won't work. What are you trying to do ? Can you explain a little bit more. It seems that you open a file read it and try to write the exact same thing into the same file ???

Comment: Actually I am reading the file first then I need to do perform some changes in the file. Here I have shown image file but I have to use .txt, .doc, .job files. After reading the file I need to write in it and finally save/update in the same location.

Answer (score 0):

This post explains how to both read and write to a file using a single stream:

[How to both read and write a file in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605685/how-to-both-read-and-write-a-file-in-c-sharp)

Consider you may have the file still open from a previous erroneous run. Use a tool like Sysinternals Process Monitor or Unlocker to verify it isn't open by another instance.

How to use Process Monitor:

http://www.manuelmeyer.net/2013/09/tooltips-unlocking-files-with-sysinternals-process-monitor/

Answer (score 0):

Both `source` and `dest` are referencing the same file. In the first instance (`source`) you open it exclusively (ie not shared).

In the second instance (`dest`) you now want to create the file which you opened in the first instance, but allow it to be shared.

Since the `source` is already open an in use you cannot write over the top of it using `dest`.

I think what you may be really want is to have the `path` parameter for the `dest` to be different to `path` parameter for the `source`, since you are essentially trying to re-write the same data into the same file at the same location right now.